# How do I get the number of seconds between two DateTimes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I've got code that does time tracking for employees.  It creates a counter to show the employee how long they have been clocked in for.

This is the current code:

```
  start_time = Time.parse(self.settings.first_clock_in)
  total_seconds = Time.now - start_time
  hours = (total_seconds/ 3600).to_i
  minutes = ((total_seconds % 3600) / 60).to_i
  seconds = ((total_seconds % 3600) % 60).to_i
```

This works fine.  But because Time is limited to the range of 1970 - 2038 we are trying to replace all Time uses with DateTimes.  I can't figure out how to get the number of seconds between two DateTimes.  Subtracting them yields a Rational which I don't know how to interpret, whereas subtracting Times yields the difference in seconds.

NOTE: Since Ruby 1.9.2, the hard limit of Time is removed. However, Time is optimized for values between 1823-11-12 and 2116-02-20.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Subtracting two DateTimes returns the elapsed time in days, so you could just do:

```
elapsed_seconds = ((end_time - start_time) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i
```

Comment: Ah, I knew it returned it in days, I didn't know that this would include fractions of a day as well.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly in case of a Leap second (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Comment: Just a note to anyone else who may be confused by this. Yes, subtracting two `DateTime`s returns elapsed time in days. However, in Rails a model attribute that you migrate as `datetime` may actually be an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, and subtracting two of those returns elapsed time in *seconds*.

Comment: I'm using this and getting a fraction, the datetimes are 2 seconds apart, 15 and 13, but I'm getting 1.939s instead of 2s and .to_i is truncating to 1 second.

Answer (score 53):

Or, more readably:

```
diff = datetime_1 - datetime_2
diff * 1.days # => difference in seconds; requires Ruby on Rails
```

Note, what you or some other searchers might really be looking for is this:

```
diff = datetime_1 - datetime_2
Date.day_fraction_to_time(diff) # => [h, m, s, frac_s]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working with me for (created_at and updated_at). My two numbers are `2016-08-07 20:33:54.863568` and `2016-08-07 20:33:54.788684`, but the difference is 6469.9776. Posgres says those fields are 'timestamps without time zone', if that makes a difference.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `days' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: note that .days is a rails method and is not available in ruby without it.

Comment: This should also help => `diff.days.seconds`

Answer (score 34):

You can convert them to floats with `to_f`, though this will incur the usual loss of precision associated with floats. If you're just casting to an integer for whole seconds it shouldn't be big enough to be a worry.

The results are in seconds:

```
>> end_time.to_f - start_time.to_f
=> 7.39954495429993

>> (end_time.to_f - start_time.to_f).to_i
=> 7
```

Otherwise, you could look at using `to_formatted_s` on the DateTime object and seeing if you can coax the output into something the `Decimal` class will accept, or just formatting it as plain Unix time as a string and calling `to_i` on that.

Comment: Thanks Luke, .to_f conversion is great! It works independently of Date class: either it's a DateTime or ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `to_f' for #<DateTime:0x00000002240840>

Answer (score 27):

### Time

No need to rely on fractions or helper functions. It's much simpler than that. `Time` itself is integer underneath. Here's the Ruby way:

```
stop.to_i - start.to_i
```

Example:

```
#!ruby
> start = Time.now
 => 2016-06-21 14:55:36 -0700
> stop = start + 5.seconds
 => 2016-06-21 14:55:41 -0700
> stop.to_i - start.to_i
 => 5
```

### DateTime

`DateTime` on the other hand returns a `Rational` after subtraction, which is a fraction of a day. So you can still do:

```
((dt2 - dt1) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i
```

or

```
((dt2 - dt2) * 86400).to_i
```

By example:

```
#!ruby
> dt1 = DateTime.new(2024, 3, 11, 12, 0, 0)
> dt2 = DateTime.new(2024, 3, 11, 12, 30, 0)
> (dt2 - dt1)
 => (1/48)
> (dt2 - dt1).class
 => Rational
> difference_in_seconds = ((dt2 - dt1) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i
 => 1800
```

Answer (score 8):

I am using ruby-2.1.4 and for me the following worked

```
Time.now - Time.new(2014,11,05,17,30,0)
```

gave me the time difference in **seconds**

reference: [ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Time.html#method-i-2D)

Comment: OP is referring to "DateTime" Object not a "Time" object.

Answer (score 1):

there's a method made for that:

`Time.now.minus_with_coercion(10.seconds.ago)`

equals 10.

Source: http://apidock.com/rails/Time/minus_with_coercion

Hope I helped.

Comment: We are talking about DateTime class not Time class.

Answer (score 1):

Define a Ruby function like this,

```
def time_diff(start_time, end_time)
  seconds_diff = (start_time - end_time).to_i.abs

  days = seconds_diff / 86400 
  seconds_diff -= days * 86400

  hours = seconds_diff / 3600  
  seconds_diff -= hours * 3600

  minutes = seconds_diff / 60
  seconds_diff -= minutes * 60

  seconds = seconds_diff

  "#{days} Days #{hours} Hrs #{minutes} Min #{seconds} Sec"
 end
```

And Call this function,

```
time_diff(Time.now, Time.now-4.days-2.hours-1.minutes-53.seconds)
```