# how to get time difference in minutes in rails for two date time fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, difference

i want to calculate time difference in  minutes between two date_time fields.like created_at and updated_at kind of fields. i want the result like this `updated_at - created_at = some minutes.`

these times are present in  time zone of INDIA. how can i do that in rails?

```
created = article.created_at
updated = article.updated_at

minutes = updated - created
```

Comment: Could you clear some things here. What do you really meant by `date_time` fields? The fields of datatype `DateTime`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As `created_at` and `updated_at` are of type `DateTime`, this should work.

```
created = article.created_at
updated = article.updated_at
minutes = ((updated - created) * 24 * 60).to_i
```

***Explanation:***

Subtracting two DateTimes returns *[the elapsed time in days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567636/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-seconds-between-two-datetimes-in-ruby-on-rails)*. In the below example `e-d` will return `(28807336643183/28800000000000)`. So to convert this into *minutes*, we need to **multiply** it by `24*60`(As the day has 24 hours and each hour has 60 minutes)

***Example(tested):***

```
d = DateTime.now
 => Tue, 13 Jun 2017 10:21:59 +0530 
2.3.3 :003 > e = DateTime.now + 1.day
 => Wed, 14 Jun 2017 10:22:21 +0530
g = ((e-d) * 24 * 60).to_i
 => 1440
```

Comment: Sorry but how does this work? `updated - created` will give you a time difference in seconds, which should be divided by 60 to give you minutes. I have no idea why you're multiplying these seconds by the number of minutes in a day...

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  I've put the correct answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953115/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-rails-for-two-date-time-fields/39254215#39254215)

Comment: Careful @Doug I got downvoted for questioning this answer and providing a correct solution. Seems to be some gaming going on here... 5 upvotes for an utterly and completely wrong answer? Can't be explained logically...

Comment: @toxaq Did you read the question? `created_at` and `updated_at` are of type **DateTime** not **Time**. So this is the correct answer and your answer wrong!

Comment: @Doug Did you read the question? `created_at` and `updated_at` are of type **DateTime** not **Time**. So this is the correct answer and your answer wrong!

Comment: @toxaq And nothing is going on here! I got upvotes because its a **correct answer**. Its simple as that!

Comment: @pavan I queried it first with no reply. It's incredibly astute of you to noticed that created_at and updated_at have gone against the convention of Rails and used Datetime fields instead of the standard timestamp. Kudos to you! I think that deserves some extra explanation considering a number of people have made that exact query and provided the solution as per convention. Again, well done you for spotting the devil in the detail.

Comment: @pavan haha, never not friends! My initial query was an echo in the dark :P Can you add some clarification around timestamp vs datetime for others like Doug and myself that got thoroughly confused? I've deleted my answer already.

Comment: @toxaq Sure! I'll add that!

Comment: @toxaq You meant *time vs datetime*?

Comment: @pavan well this adds more confusion really. Created_at and updated_at are added using `t.timestamps` in a Rails migration. In Postgres at least, this creates a `timestamp without time zone` field and if you check the class of a model.created_at/updated_at it will be an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, which is Time like. So any clarification would be good around class vs column and the convention.

Comment: @toxaq I'll clear it up for sure. Give me some time :)

Comment: @toxaq `:datetime` and `:timestamp` will default to *DATETIME* while `:time` default to *TIME* check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928275/in-ruby-on-rails-whats-the-difference-between-datetime-timestamp-time-and-da. I want to ask how you got `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`?

Comment: @pavan The question doesn't say `DateTime`, it says `date_time` which is not a real thing.  It also says `date time` which is also not a thing.  

Most people coming to this question from Google are going to be referring to ActiveRecord models with `TimeWithZone` (this is how I discovered it), and your answer is incorrect in that case.  

I assume that OP meant Article was an ActiveRecord model, and that `created_at` and `updated_at` are the default `TimeWithZone`, not `DateTime`

OP also says times are in Time Zone of India.  `DateTime` does not contain that information.

Comment: @Doug Lets not heatup the argument here. I agree that the Question is bit unclear and also misleading. But I don't agree with `DateTime` don't have `TimeZone`. It does **has time zones**. The `+530` in my example is the `timezone`. You can check the [*docs*](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html). I hope OP clears some confusion so that we both can end up as good!

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated my answer to specify that it works with `TimeWithZone`  Unfortunately I am unable to edit my comment.

Comment: WRONG! do not use this method. Use @Doug method.

Comment: The above calculation is wrong. the difference between two times returns seconds, dividing it by 60 you can convert it into minutes. It should be (updated - created)/60

Answer (score 46):

This solution works for ActiveRecord models using `TimeWithZone` classes for `created_at` and `updated_at`.

```
created = article.created_at
updated = article.updated_at

minutes = (updated - created) / 1.minutes
```

Comment: This will work if `created_at`/`updated_at` are instances of `Time`. Which they aren't, as claimed in Pavan's answer. I'm wondering, can it depend on an application setting or rails version or something?

Comment: This is clean and more intuitive since it indicates that the resulting units will be `minutes`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

looking at helper `time_ago_in_words`, we can say:

```
    from_time = from_time.to_time if from_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
    to_time = to_time.to_time if to_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
    #absolute distance:
    from_time, to_time = to_time, from_time if from_time > to_time
    distance_in_minutes = ((to_time - from_time)/60.0).round
```

Answer (score 0):

The data type of ActiveRecord's columns `created_at` and `updated_at` is `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. If you want to do the operation with DateTime, you need to convert it first

```
now = DateTime.now
creation_time = user.created_at.to_datetime        
diff_in_minutes = ((now - creation_time) * 24 * 60).to_i
```

You can test this easily in the Rails console, but for easier testing, you can convert it to seconds instead

```
diff_in_seconds = ((now - creation_time) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what i used and it simply takes care of days or Min's for you as well as giving you the difference [`time_ago_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words) simply pass a Datetime, Date or Time object and it will return the difference that is human readable.  `time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)`

Comment: Dwonvoted. The question asks for the result in minutes not as a string sentence.